# c++ - Android internals qestion

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

So I am trying to make c++ apps in android, and with now good tutorials I can find how to start from the ground up, I decided to start by learning everything about android its self. [This is a good explanation](http://www.cprogramming.com/android/android_getting_started.html) that I have found.

Let me know if this is correct.

So to make an app with c++ you need to use the ndk and jni to interface with java calls, and the native libraries in android were written in c/c++. SO to use the native c/c++ libraries you have to make calls to java in c++???

Comment: Warning: That tutorial is 3 major Android versions back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write everything in C/C++, use the [NativeActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html)

there is an official [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na.html) about this.

But, I don't think that's a good idea to write code in this way unless you are a game developer, and really fluent about everything about OpenGL. Becuase it is much convenient to write the UI part in OpenGL by pure C/C++.

And, in most common cases, we use part of our code by combine JNI and C/C++ to porting C/C++ dependencies to Java space.

Comment: I am currently more a software engineer, but I got into coding because game-development, and I want to get into it more, now that I have a good grasp of c++, and starting to learn GLSL/opengl. so writing completely in c++ works nicely for me. I do wonder though if things like server calls, and a lot of background processes work in c++, why not still write more advanced apps in c++ if you have a good grasp of opengl?

Answer (score 0):

Not to use native libraries.  But yes, some functionality does require you to call back into Java.  The Android framework is written in Java, and not all parts of it are exported to C.

Really I don't suggest writing an entire app in C or C++.  I suggest writing only computationally heavy parts in C++, and doing the UI in Java calling down to C++ as needed.  It just ends up cleaner that way.  THe only time I'd consider writing the GUI in C++ would be if it was pure OpenGL.

Java GUI/system interface with C++ logic is fairly common-  it allows you to write a common library between iOS/Android/desktop for the business logic and customize the UI to the platform.

Comment: Though if you are still trying for more performance, and have an understanding of opengl, isn't it still better to write everything with c++ so you can get around some of the heavier processes java uses? I mean I have never done UI in java, is it that much more simple?